# HP Pavillion Netbook Runnig Lubuntu 22.04 LTS No Wifi

Tags: networking, lubuntu, hp, ralink

Greetings to all,
I have installed Lubuntu 22.04 onto my aging HP Pavillion Netbook.
Unfortunately there is no wifi functionality.

Details are

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
        DeviceName: Roma Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi Adapter
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
        Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 40
        Memory at f0a10000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
        Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
        Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
        Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
        Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-4d-b0-ab-dc-84-0c
        Kernel driver in use: rt2800pci
        Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Thanks

Many thanks for the welcome.

rfkill

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
```

iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=off   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the result of the terminal commands: `rfkill list all` and: `iwconfig` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: "Hard blocked: yes" means that the wireless switch or key combination, something like Fn+F8, is set to turn off the wireless radio. Find it and switch it.

Comment: Pressing F12 (Wifi Switch) toggles the soft blocked but doesn't change the hard block setting. The LED 0n F12 stays Orange though.

Comment: There's nothing in the BIOS to enable Wifi either